# How to select by attribute in Dita OTs custom.xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, dita, dita-ot

My goal is to change the font color of any text that is contained within an element that has the attribute and value of `<li audience="beginner"></li>`. I'm currently looking to do this in the custom.xsl file of Dita Open Toolkits PDF plugin. The custom.xsl will override any styles in the common.xsl. My Question is how do I select by attribute in the attribute-set tag?

Custom.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:attribute-set name="li">
        <xsl:attribute name="color">red</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML

```
<li audience="beginner" class="- topic/li ">This text should be blue</li>
<li audience="expert" class="- topic/li ">This text should be red</li>
```

Comment: This would be much easier to solve in CSS. Consider leaving the output HTML as it is.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I'm transforming this XML into a PDF. The Custom.xsl in my understanding is the CSS for the translation.

Comment: You cannot select by attribute or anything else in attribute sets. You override the template for li to not use them or apply more specific matches with different sets

Comment: Does "li" template has following structure? <xsl:template match="li"><fo:list-item use-attribute-set="li">...</fo:list-item></xsl:template>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selection criteria for the OT would be something like:

```
    ...
    <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,' topic/li ')]">
        <xsl:attribute name="color">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@audience="beginner">blue</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@audience="expert">red</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>black</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
    ... (anything else you want to do with li)
    </xsl:template>
    ...
```

Hope this helps.